# how to store common values from two array

Tags: java, android

```
ArrayList<String>id=new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String>servicesid=new ArrayList<>();

for(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot:task.getResult()){
    String documentid=documentSnapshot.getId();
    id.add(documentid);
}
servicesid = getArguments().getStringArrayList("serviceid");

selectedid=servicesid.retainAll(id);
```

I am having two arrays want to get common values from that arrays.I am using retainAll to get common values.Ex:in first array  having 4 values in second array having 3 values.In this case two values are common in both arrays after doing retainAll i am getting common values but the first array is having only two values.i want the same values in first array after doing retainAll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clone it if you  don't want to mutate the `servicesid` list after the call to `retainAll`:

```
List<String> copy = new ArrayList<>(servicesid);
selectedid = copy.retainAll(id);
```

The mutation will now be applied to `copy` and `servicesid` will remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`CollectionUtils.intersection`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.2/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#intersection(java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection)) of Apache Commons:

```
Collection<String> common = CollectionUtils.intersection(id, servicesid)
```